# isssue about creating my own templated function to sort

Tags: c++, templates

I'm practicing using templates and lambdas.
I decided to make sorting function which will sort vector of any  type by declaration in lambda(very similar to `std::sort()`), but I came up with an issue.

My issue is in this line:

```
void sorting(vector<T>& files,
             int beginning,
             int end,
             std::function<bool(int, int)> compare)
```

I would like to change `std::function<bool(int, int)>` to `std::function<bool(T, T)>` as when someone wants to compare doubles I would like my template to handle it without some unpleasant conversion.

Here is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
int median_size(vector<T>files, int beginning, int end)
{
    T a = files[beginning], b = files[(end + beginning) / 2], c = files[end - 1];
    if ((a<b && a>c) || (a > b && a < c)) return a;
    else if ((b<a && b>c) || (b > a && b < c)) return b;
    else return c;
}

template <class T>
void sorting(vector<T>& files,
             int beginning,
             int end,
             std::function<bool(int, int)> compare)
{
    int left = beginning, right = end;
    T pivot = median_size(files, beginning, end);
    while (left <= right)
    {
        while (compare(files[left],pivot) ) left++;
        while (compare(pivot, files[right])) right--;
        if (left <= right)
        {
            std::swap(files[left], files[right]);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    if (right - beginning > 0) sorting(files, beginning, right, compare);
    if (end - left > 0) sorting(files, left, end, compare);
}


int main()
{
    // using lambda in my own function ex
    vector<double> values2{ 2135.2135,2134.12365,1236.11,1236.12,21366,213,2512351.123,4.32,12312,235122};
    sorting(values2, 0, values2.size() - 1, [](double a, double b) {
        return a < b;
        }
    );
    for (auto value : values2) cout << value << "\n";
}
```

fixed code:

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
template <class T>
T median(vector<T>const& values, int beginning, int end)
{
    T a = values[beginning], b = values[(end + beginning) / 2], c = values[end - 1];
    if ((a<b && a>c) || (a > b && a < c)) return a;
    else if ((b<a && b>c) || (b > a && b < c)) return b;
    else return c;
}
template <typename T, typename F>
void sorting(vector<T>& values, int beginning, int end, F compare)
{
    int left = beginning, right = end;
    T pivot = median(values, beginning, end);
    while (left <= right)
    {
        while (compare(values[left],pivot) ) left++;
        while (compare(pivot, values[right])) right--;
        if (left <= right)
        {
            std::swap(values[left], values[right]);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    if (right - beginning > 0) sorting(values, beginning, right, compare);
    if (end - left > 0) sorting(values, left, end, compare);
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> values{ 2135,2134,1236,21366,12312,2351232 };
    std::sort(std::begin(values), std::end(values),
        // i can use auto if variable type is long or hard, but when its simply 
        //inteager i will just set it as int 
        [](int  a, int b)
        {
            return a < b;
        });
    for (auto value : values) cout << value << "\n";
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    auto p = std::make_unique<int>(65);
    //lambda function cannot change value of variables sent by reference
    // it will only be changed inside lambda scope, but after leaving scope 
    //value will return to previous value
    auto lambda = [&p]() {
        cout << "value: " << *p << "\n";
    };
    cout << *p<<"\n";
    vector<double> values2{ 2135.2135,2134.12365,1236.11,1236.12,21366,12312,235122};
    sorting(values2, 0, values2.size() - 1, [](double a, double b) {
        return a < b;
        }
    );
    for (auto value : values2) cout << value << "\n";
}
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried to do that?

Comment: Obligatory "Avoid `using namespace std`" advice.

Comment: @molbdnilo _"And what happened when you tried to do that?"_Well, "issues"

Comment: It's more convenient to let the function type also be a template parameter. And `median_size` (which is a pretty odd name) should take the vector by const reference and return `T`, not `int`.

Comment: @molbdnilo i get error: no instance of function template "sorting" matches the argument list.

Comment: @AndyG thanks, I already changed this.

Comment: @molbdnilo yeah i modified it, your right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with:

```
template <class T>
void foo(std::vector<T>&, std::function<bool(T, T)>)
```

- is that `T` is deducible from several place and should match
- lambda is NOT a `std::function`, even if convertible to.

One possibility is to get rid of `std::function` and take any callable (Possibly use concept in C++20)

```
template <typename T, typename F>
requires std::predicate<F, T, T>
void foo(std::vector<T>&, F)
```

Another option is to make some `T` non-deducible (with C++20 [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) or your own before)

```
template <class T>
void foo(std::vector<T>&, std::type_identity_t<std::function<bool(T, T)>>)
```

Comment: I used the option with taking callable, works fine after this modification, thank you.